# It's a little low on grist

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

In the movie *Easy A*, Emma Stone's character has the following conversation with her parents:

> Mother: *What's the rumor mill churning out these days, anything interesting?*
>   Girl: *You know, not really. Not really, it's a little low on grist.*
>   Father: *Whoa! Clever wordplay. I like it very much. You must be related to me.*
>   Girl: *Only by marriage.*
>  
>   Father: *Give it to me.*

I want to know the meaning of 2 phrases:

1. It's a little low on grist
2. give it to me

Comment: I'm a native English speaker, and I haven't a clue what the first one is about. I've never heard of "grisp", and while the Urban Dictionary has an entry, it doesn't seem to fit. Are you sure you're not mishearing (but I can't think of anything it might be a mistake for)?

Comment: It's grist, you need more context to understand.  Edited.

Comment: @z7sg: Thanks, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Grist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grist) is what you grind in a mill.  Since the rumor mill is low on grist, that means there isn't much in the way of gossip these days.  *Grist to/for the mill* also has the idiomatic meaning of "something that can be employed to someone's advantage" often when the something does not appear advantageous.

So the double meaning here is that there is not much gossip that she can exploit for her own ends.  It really is a clever play on words.

The "give it to me" part I couldn't say.  It could mean "tell me what little gossip you've heard" or it might mean "hand me that thing" or it might mean "keep up the witty reparté."  There's really not enough context to tell.

EDIT: "Only by marriage" means that they are only related through marriage, not by "blood" or genetic ties.  How this relates to their relationship, I don't know.  Is he her step-father?  In any case, she is teasing him; if they are only related by marriage then she didn't inherit her cleverness from *him*, which is what he is suggesting by saying "you must be related to me."

Comment: Hey, it's [grist to the mill](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/grist-to-the-mill.html).  :)

Comment: and what's only by marriage??

Comment: @Sergey See edit about "only by marriage." @z7sg Thanks. Damn prepositions.

Comment: @z7sg: Google Ngrams shows both "grist to the mill" and "grist for the mill." And looking at Google Book's examples of their use in the 1800's, "grist to the mill" originally meant profit or gain, and "grist for the mill" originally meant raw material. For example: *"Luckily, there is no want of materials for this disposition to work upon, there is plenty of grist for the mill."* and *"But there is a dearth of workers in these fields; for it is well known that such work does not bring grist to the mill, at least to many."* But it appears that even then people got these two idioms confused.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the search. I updated my answer again.

Comment: Here's the [movie clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oTeK2lBpdg&feature=related). The dialogue in question starts at :50 and involves both the mother and the father. See [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=give+it+to+me) for this use of _give it to me_.

Comment: @Peter I tried ngrams but oddly must have made a typo. Also it seems to me that *for* is a corruption introduced by Americans.

Comment: @z7sg: e.g., Westminster Review, by Jeremy Bentham, Sir John Bowring, John Stuart Mill (1832) *It is grist for the mill of political mathematics; though it might be vain to predicate at this moment what precise form of bread kind the result shall ultimately take.* This is a different idiom (not meaning *profit or gain,* which is what early dictionaries give for a definition of *grist to the mill*, but meaning raw materials). I believe there are other uses of the *for* idiom, although this idiom was definitely introduced later, and was not as common. Now these two idioms seem to have merged.

Comment: "tell me what little gossip you've heard" can't be true, with all due respect, for the reason that when Emma uses sarcasm to her dad in such a little bitty intense manner saying "only by marriage" her dad uses sarcasm in response even a bit more intense by saying that now that only marriage relates us, give me what husbands and wives give to each other ...referring also to one of Madonna's songs named "give it to me" in which Madonna keeps asking a man to give her what she wants...sorry if i am being a bit vague i hope my explanation has been clear enough and to the point

Comment: The 'give it to me' part is the third option: 'keep up the witty reparté'. Emma Stone's character, Olive, is inherently intelligent and the conversations with her parents throughout the film reflect this. Her father in particular feels that it is important to keep a humourous perspective on serious and trivial matters alike and he displays his own intelligence and depth whilst keeping a jovial attitude at various points. After the 'low on grist' line, 'only by marriage' was yet more clever wordplay. Olive was simply stating that without her parents' marriage she would not be there.